# Getting the column choice values from a matrix table using Qualtrics API

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have a matrix with two columns. I want to get the inputs of both columns on page submit. I have been using `getChoiceValue`, and I have no problem getting the value of the right column. How can I get the value of the left column?

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function()
{
// this does not work
  let left_column_choice = this.getChoiceValue(0);
// this works for sure
  let right_column_choice = this.getChoiceValue(1); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about 'Qualtrics' or any functions it contains,
but if you are looking for a plain vanilla JS solution, this might help.

```js
function getColumnInfo (cols,c) {
  let arr = [],
      sel = document.querySelectorAll('.tbl td');
  for( const [ndx,val] of sel.entries(sel) ) {
    if ((ndx % cols) == c) arr.push(val.textContent) 
  };
  return arr;
}
let info = getColumnInfo(4,1);  // of 4 column table, get column 1
alert('Column #2 contents:\n'+info);
```

```html
<table border='1' class='tbl'>
<caption> Table </caption>

 <tr>
  <td>Group 1 </td>
  <td>A </td>
  <td>a </td>
  <td>1 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Group 2 </td>
  <td>B </td>
  <td>b </td>
  <td>2 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Group 3 </td>
  <td>C </td>
  <td>c </td>
  <td>3 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```